# Program structure...getting lost

Tags: c#, class

Can someone guide me a little on whats best way to do this...am getting muddled up with my classes...where to put things.

- **Main form**: Sets up classes and passes dblocation to ApplicationEnvironment, calls Getdata from DataAccess
- **ApplicationEnvironment**: Stores Global variables that other classes may need... ie dbLocation
- **DataAccess**: This handles calls from form to get data and return, it uses the dbLocation

So I jump onto form setup ApplicationEnvironment give it database location

```
dblocation = "xxxx"
ApplicationEnvironment appSet = new ApplicationEnvironment();
appSet.dbLocation=@"S:\Database\database.accdb";
```

Then setup DataAccess class

```
DataAccess datAcc = new DataAccess();
DataSet ds;
ds= datAcc.GetData();
```

So in the DataAccess class I wan to use dbLocation thats be setup in ApplicationEnvironment class... I cant seem to call it

```
public DataSet GetData(){
string mydatabase = ApplicationEnvironment.dbLocation;
```

Error is

> "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property"

Should be ApplicationEnvironment.dbLocation.get?

Anyone know of any good examples of mixing classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close to creating a good structure to you application, but with a couple of mistakes

#### Structure

The form is not the right place to be setting the rest of the app up. That should happen in the main application, or if a large undertaking, in a setup class:

Main application: Sets up classes. Sets up ApplicationEnvironment. Passes DataAccess to MainForm and ApplicationEnvironment to DataAccess.

Main form: Calls Getdata from DataAccess

ApplicationEnvironment: Stores configuration values that other classes may need... ie dbLocation (**do not call them global variables; these are evil things and you aren't using them**)

DataAccess: This handles calls from form to get data and return, it uses the dbLocation

#### Code

In your setup code (in main application), you'd expose aspects of the system to interested parties:

```
ApplicationEnvironment appSet = new ApplicationEnvironment();
appSet.dbLocation=@"S:\Database\database.accdb";
DataAccess datAcc = new DataAccess(appSet);
MainForm form = new MainForm(datAcc);
...
```

Then, within DataAccess, you can do something like:

```
Class DataAccess
{
    private readonly string _dbLocation;

    public DataAccess(string dbLocation)
    {
        _dbLocation = dbLocation;
    }

    public SomeType GetData()
    {
        // use _dbLocation to access DB
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for that.... I have implemented that.... but when I pass the datAcc to MainForm  (MainForm(datAcc)) then I cant deem to reference it.

Comment: got it working now the class file had somehow become not a c# file... weird... Created new class copied over contents all good. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate issue can be solved in one of two ways (at least that I'm going to name :))

Create an instance of ApplicationEnvironment

```
public DataSet GetData(){
ApplicationEnvironment ae = new ApplicationEnvironment();
string mydatabase = ae.dbLocation;
```

Make ApplicationEnvironment and its members static

```
public static class ApplicationEnvironment
{
    public static string dbLocation = @"S:\Database\database.accdb";
}
```

when static, your existing call of

```
public DataSet GetData(){
string mydatabase = ApplicationEnvironment.dbLocation;
```

will work.

Some info on static classes/methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

The error:

> "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Basically just means you have to instantiate an object of `ApplicationEnvironment` to access it's inner workings.  Static classes/methods don't have this restriction and can be called directly - [though they ***can*** have their own set of issues.](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/01/29/static-methods-will-shock-you/)